# cmd.exe vs & for executing batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to execute a batch(`*.bat`) file from Powershell. Is there any reason not to use option 1 below?

1. `& path-to-batch-file`
2. `cmd.exe /c path-to-batch-file`

Comment: There is no practical difference between the two. #1 is more typical and readable from a PowerShell perspective.

Comment: The ampersand is not required either!

Comment: @Compo I use this command in a `;` separated sequence and pipe the output. If I omit the ampersand the command is not executed but simply treated as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of corner cases...

Option 1 probably uses the default file handler for .bat files. If that handler is changed, corrupted, or different than expected, a problem could arise. Though, this seems pretty unlikely.

Option 2 gives you the power to pass [additional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) to `cmd.exe`, which might be valuable.

Option 2 *might* be slightly faster, but it's only a guess: in Option 1 powershell might need to lookup the shell handler for batch files from the registry first, then execute those instructions, whereas Option 2 needs only find the `cmd.exe` executable and run it with supplied parameters.

Comment: Option 2 will be slower because it has to search `$env:path` to find `cmd.exe`. Compare `trace-command -name CommandDiscovery -Expression {& c:\test\test.bat} -PSHost` and `trace-command -name CommandDiscovery -Expression {cmd.exe /c c:\test\test.bat} -PSHost`. With a full `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` it does the same steps either way, but then it's hard-coding a location for cmd.exe which might not be correct.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Interesting. I guess the registry *is* probably already in memory.